# What should be good approach for recording sound and take a photo like this?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation

I need to make an sample app that can record audio and take photos. The start ui should be simple as it has: camera preview, a button.

When users touch down, the audio recording should be started, and the image should be taken as users touch up.

What should be best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/: [SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007802) + [PhotoPicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196) (30 samples)